# Pulling the limit inside the integral for Real Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2 \cos\sqrt\frac{{2xn+2}}{xn+1}\,dx$$

I just saw this on an exam, and I wondered if I did it right.

I said that since $\cos x$ is continuous and bounded, I could pull the limit inside the integral. Am I also allowed to then pull the limit inside the cos and square root? I got an answer of $\cos\sqrt2$.

Comment: For help with formatting, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Which theorem you used? For pulling the limit inside the integral?

Comment: What I see is the fact that $\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}=2$, you don't even need to switch the limit and integral...

Comment: @FrankLu You're still switching limit and integral

Comment: "I said that since $\cos x$ is continuous and bounded, I could pull the limit inside the integral." And from which result does this come from?

Comment: @zhw $\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}=2$ for all $x>0, n>0$, thus it becomes the limit of a constant. I didn't see where I switched limit and integral.

Comment: @FrankLu Of course you are right!. Missed the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to switch any limit with any integral.

Notice that

$$2xn + 2 = 2(xn + 1)$$

Hence your integral is simply

$$\int_1^2 \cos\sqrt{2}\ dx = \cos\sqrt{2} + C$$

The limit becomes irrelevant.

Comment: why is there a constant here?

Comment: @qbert Because I like to write $0$ in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about pulling the limit inside being allowed in general.

The answer is: sometimes.

In particular, if the sequence of integrands converges UNIFORMLY, then you can. In general, you cannot. This is considered by many to be the single most frustrating weakness of the Riemann integral, and is a strong motivation for the construction of the Lebesgue integral, which is better behaved with limits.

For the purposes of the Riemann integral, continuous and bounded is not sufficient to justify moving the limit inside.

You will likely cover this, although it seems unrelated, when you study infinite series.

Please see Turing's answer below for why this approach is unnecessary in this particular instance.

Comment: The problem might have been something that was a little less nice. Let's say that I could not reduce it. Since cosine is bounded, by the bounded convergence theorem, could I pull the limit inside?

Comment: @Fleetwoodmac Oh maybe I was mistaken, I had gotten the impression you were not familiar with the lebesgue integral. In that case, yes, as qberts answer shows. They are uniformly bounded by 1. Best to also mention that the continuous part implies they are measurable as well.

Comment: @Fleetwoodmac Also very important to note that you need them uniformly bounded, not just bounded, in this instance that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exchange the limit and the integral here, although it is not necessary as you see, dominated convergence works,
$$
\left|\cos\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}}\right)\right |\leq 1
$$
and $g=1$ is integrable on $[1,2]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^2 \cos\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}}\right)\mathrm dx\\
=
\int_1^2\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}}\right)\mathrm dx\\
=
\int_1^2 \cos\left (\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{2xn+2}{xn+1}}\right)\mathrm dx\\
=\cos\sqrt{2}\int_1^2\mathrm dx=\cos\sqrt{2}
$$